# Fullcalendar cell size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/).

In Month view I made all the events the same size independent of their title.

Now I want all the cells to be the same size no matter how much events there are for specific date. If there are more events than can fit in the cell I want just to show only those who can fit in the cell and add something like: 
"2 more..." at the bottom of a cell.

To do this I need to know how does the FullCalendar determines the size of a cells based on number of the events which are shown in the cell and how it resizes cells when new events are added by drag&drop.
I see in html code that events are not actually put in the cell table, but it appears that they are in the cell by using absolute positioning so I guess some javascript is used also to calculate the size of cells.

Maybe I should mention that I don't put the size of the calendar, I need it to use default 100% width of its container.

Comment: Why did this question got two downvotes? I think that my question was clear, and I was looking for the answer before I posted it but I couldnt find it anywhere.

Comment: Hey @Kretosh - I think I know what you want

I added this to my CSS...
`code` #calendar tr td.fc-first div div.fc-day-content div {
 max-height: 50px;
        overflow: hidden;
}`code`
Max height prevents the "post-render" height change from taking effect, and overflow prevents the extra items from being displayed (even though they're there in the DOM)... then it's up to you to add an eventRender to the fullcalendar to count the number of events in a day and display the appropriate message....